# Is it possible to add my own custom transformation plugin to Cloud data fusion either in Basic edition or in Enterprise edition. Please enlighten

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-data-fusion

As I understand there are many transformation plug-ins available in Google cloud data fusion Hub. However, if I want to create my own specific custom plug-in, can I add that plug-in to Google data fusion and use in my pipeline? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a custom plugin to `DataFusion` (considering that you have already implemented it), you have to follow the steps bellow:

1) Click on the `+` button

[image]

2) Click on upload in the Plugin part

[image]

3) Drag your plugin `JAR` to the box, click next and then drag your plugin `JSON` to the box. You can alto just click in the box and select your JAR/JSON. After that, just click in finish.

[image]

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can write custom transformations using the SDK provided. You can also deploy it in basic or enterprise edition. You can find examples at https://github.com/data-integrations

Nitin

Comment: Dear Nitin, my question was more for GCP’s Cloud data fusion. How do you add custom plugins to Cloud data fusion. Thanks.